# Proving that a function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

This is one part of an exercise in my homework, which for some reason I can't think of any way to prove.

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$, if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $0$ otherwise.

I'm trying to prove that this function is bounded. I have figured that I only need to prove it for $x\geq 0$, since $f(x,y)=-f(-x,y)$, but I can't really get around to why this is bounded near $0$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried letting $z=y^2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:  $(x-y^2)^2 \ge 0$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: +1. This is a really elegant hint. You might want to replace $>$ with $\ge$

Comment: @Sivaram:  I noticed it about the same time.  Fixed.

Comment: @Leonardo Once you have solved the problem using the hint, you might want to look into the [arithmetic-geometric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), which is a generalization of the idea behind the hint, and a useful tool to have in your arsenal.

Comment: @Aaron I'm well aware of that, thanks.

Great hint, the answer comes practically for free.

Comment: It took me a second to see what you were getting at, but I really appreciate this hint. Nicely constructed.